Caption text doesn't set from expl3 token list when called with polyglossia
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands, forceheadingpunctuation=false]{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{Arial}
\setmonofont{Courier New}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\Figure{m}
 {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
    \begin{figure}[htp]
        \centering
        \includegraphics{#1}
        \caption{\l_tmpa_tl}
    \end{figure}
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\Figure{изображение}
\Figure{example-image-b}

\Figure{example-image-a}
\Figure{изображение}
\end{document}

Изображение is any image. For this image it should output caption with this word.
If I run it, I will get TimesNewRoman(0) in captions. If I comment polyglossia statements, everything except for russian will be correct.

please make your example compilable so we can reproduce the error. that means not requiring images people don't have and not depending on fonts most people don't have. use fonts included in TeX Live if at all possible and stick to the standard images. you should only use proprietary fonts if your issue cannot otherwise be reproduced.

I think you also want to use ~ for the spaces in the caption text rather than \ . I have a suspicion the latter may just happen to work (assuming it does) because ~ is, as far as I know, the documented way to specify spaces.

On Windows  use \setsansfont{Arial Unicode MS}  rather than Arial. Alo please also change изображение  to publicly availabel images like you did for the rest

\l_tmpa_tl is a general temporary variable that every one can use. Do not assume that it stays unchanged if there is code between your setting and using it. Use your own variable instead.

How long is ‘short-term’?

The expl3 manual tells you about the risks of using \l_tmpa_tl. What does ‘short-term’ mean?
It means that from the moment you set the variable to the moment you use it, nothing intervenes that's not under your precise control.
In your example, \begin{figure} is definitely out of your control and, indeed, polyglossia does things during \begin{figure} that change the value stored in \l_tmpa_tl.
Solution: declare your own temporary variable.
\tl_new:N \l__intolighther_caption_tl

\NewDocumentCommand\Figure{m}
 {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__intolighther_caption_tl {#1}

    \begin{figure}[htp]
        \centering
        \includegraphics{#1}
        \caption{\l__intolighther_caption_tl}
    \end{figure}
 }

Of course, this example is too simplistic and likely you want to do some work with \l__intolighther_caption_tl, but that's the idea. Note that \tl_new:N must go outside the definition of \Figure, otherwise at the second call of \Figure you'd get an error.

I can't compile your example as I have neither the first image nor the fonts. However, you want to pass \caption the value of the variable \l_tmpa_tl rather than passing it the variable itself.
\cs_new_protected:Nn \intolighter_caption:n {\caption{#1}} 
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \intolighter_caption:n {V} 

Then use
\infolighter_caption:V \l_tmpa_tl

in the definition.
Or use
\ExpandArgs {V} \caption \l_tmpa_tl

or
\exp_args:NV \caption \l_tmpa_tl

in the definition directly.
Edit
Here's a modified example to reproduce the problem. This doesn't require any Russian text. Nor does it require any images. The problem occurs with English captions also.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands, forceheadingpunctuation=false]{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\Figure{m}
{
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
  \begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    % \includegraphics{#1}
    \caption{\l_tmpa_tl}
  \end{figure}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\Figure{изображение}
\Figure{example-image-b}

\Figure{example-image-a}
\Figure{изображение}
\end{document}

And here's the modified example showing that either of the methods described above fixes the problem:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[babelshorthands, forceheadingpunctuation=false]{russian}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage{newcomputermodern}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \intolighter_caption:n {\caption{#1}}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \intolighter_caption:n {V}

\NewDocumentCommand\Figure{m}
{
  \begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 }
    \intolighter_caption:V \l_tmpa_tl
    \exp_args:NV \caption \l_tmpa_tl
  \end{figure}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\Figure{изображение}
\Figure{example-image-b}

\Figure{example-image-a}
\Figure{изображение}
\end{document}


The second method just passes the value of the variable \l_tmpa_tl to \caption rather than the variable itself using either expl3 or document-level syntax. The first does the same but less directly (But is nice if you need this a lot as it makes the code clearer and easier to adjust.)
But I would instead suggest using a different interface. A document-level command which hard codes the content of captions is clearly not a realistic example, so I assume you are actually determining the value of the caption in some other way. The best way to define the command then depends on whether the content is determined directly by the user or programmatically.
If it is determined image-by-image in the document, a key-value interface would make sense. If it is being constructed programmatically, obviously a different approach is appropriate.

These are fonts russian use in documents. Neither of these works. Caption is constructed programmatically.

@Intolighter then provide code people can test.

@Intolighter and there are fonts in TeX Live you can use to typeset Russian.

What's wrong with my mwe? Times New Roman is the font I need to use, or I can't use Latex.

@Intolighter I don't have картинк. I don't have TNR. I don't have Arial. I don't have Courier New. I am not saying you shouldn't use these fonts in you document. of course you may use whichever fonts you wish. but this is an example you want help with, so you want to make it possible for other people to reproduce the problem. that means using fonts we all have and images we all have unless the problem cannot be reproduced e.g. it is a specific problem with TNR and you've tried with other fonts and they're fine. it's just TNR you have trouble with. or just this one image file.

@Intolighter if you cannot reproduce the issue with fonts from TeX Live, you should explain this in the question. in that case, you hope somebody with those fonts will be able and willing to help, but obviously there are fewer people who might help you in that case. but nobody has a copy of картинк but you. so try to reproduce without it. if you can't, explain the problem only occurs with this particular image and we'll need a copy of the image.

Картинк is russian for image. You can use any image. I meant that it should print caption with russian letters.

@Intolighter so set the example up that way ;). if I sent you a file with \includegraphics{delwedd} would you guess I meant you to substitute some other file and add a caption in welsh? could you add a caption in welsh easily?

@Intolighter please see edit for a modified example which demonstrates the problem and a version which shows that either suggested fix solves it. of course, I cannot show this with TNR, so my erroneous output has a different font name in place of the caption.

@Intolighter but you should use a different variable as ulrike says. in the fix here it doesn't matter as there is no code between the setting and the use. but in your original example there is and in your real document there is likely more alien code, any of which might use that variable.
